# ParticleSystem initially inactive

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, particle-system

As far as I understand particle system will start emitting once it's added to parent node. How can I add it to parent but not start it, so initially it will be inactive? Then whenever I need I can use `resetSystem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send `stopSystem` to stop the particle emitter from emitting more particles.  This will let existing particles continue until their lifetimes expire.

Send `resetSystem` to start the particle emitter.  This will kill all existing particles but make the system start emitting new particles.

If you want to prevent the system from emitting any particles in the first place, set its `emissionRate` to 0 before adding it to its parent.  Then set `emissionRate` to a positive number when you want it to emit particles.  Take a look at the implementation of [`-[CCParticleSystem update:]`](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop-v2/cocos2d/CCParticleSystem.m#L487) method for details.

Also, as far as I can tell, the parent doesn't start the particle system.  Instead, the particle system is simply created in the active state.  Did you try sending `stopSystem` to the system before adding it to its parent?  (Setting the `totalParticles` of a `CCParticleSystemQuad` also appears to reset the particle system to active.)

Comment: `stopSystem` will not stop particles that are already active right after adding to parent node. This is from doc: `stop emitting particles. Running particles will continue to run until they die`. I don't want any particle to be emitted right after adding to parent node, until I `resetSystem`.

Comment: I have amended my answer.